# How to solve "Github fail to clone the repository". I am using Github for windows Gui version

Tags: github

```
2015-08-14 19:13:13.3920|WARN|thread: 1|StandardUserErrors|Showing user error Failed to get list of branches.
LibGit2Sharp.InvalidSpecificationException: 'https://github.com/gouravwalia1990/TMM' is not a valid remote name.
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_branch_upstream_name(RepositorySafeHandle handle, String canonicalReferenceName)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Branch.ResolveTrackedBranch()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Branch.get_TrackedBranch()
   at GitHub.ConcurrentRepositoryConnection.<GetBranches>b__16(Branch x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ExceptIterator>d__99`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at GitHub.ConcurrentRepositoryConnection.<GetBranches>b__13()
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Defer`1.Eval()
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Defer`1._.Run()
2015-08-14 19:12:03.6625|INFO|thread: 1|CommandLineHandler|Parsing command line arguments:C:\Users\gopal\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZQWGNE9R.3YE\60LC4KXB.QK2\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0002.000e_114545a4195e25d4\GitHub.exe
2015-08-14 19:12:03.7836|INFO|thread: 1|AppInstanceCommunicator|Starting up as master instance of GitHub for Windows
2015-08-14 19:12:04.1709|INFO|thread: 5|StartupLogging|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit, you are not providing a valid repository name.

```
LibGit2Sharp.InvalidSpecificationException: 'https://github.com/gouravwalia1990/TMM' is not a valid remote name.
```

It looks like you're not using the correct url to the repo, but the url to the repo's webpage.

You can find the repo url on the webpage: https://github.com/gouravwalia1990/TMM.

```
HTTPS clone URL : https://github.com/gouravwalia1990/TMM.git
```